# What value should I use for OnlyBelowVersion in InnoSetup for Windows 2000 only?

Tags: inno-setup, windowsversion

I want to use OnlyBelowVersion to install the sc.exe program if the Windows version is 2000 and not at all for Windows NT and below.

What is the only below version required for Windows 2000 only, ie what is the minimum windows XP or Windows 2003 string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the InnoSetup help file:

> Windows versions:
>
> 4.0.950 Windows 95
>
> 4.0.1111 Windows 95 OSR 2 & OSR 2.1
>
> 4.0.1212 Windows 95 OSR 2.5
>
> 4.1.1998 Windows 98
>
> 4.1.2222 Windows 98 Second Edition
>
> 4.9.3000 Windows Me
>
> Windows NT versions:
>
> 4.0.1381 Windows NT 4.0
>
> 5.0.2195 Windows 2000
>
> 5.01.2600 Windows XP or Windows XP 64-Bit Edition Version 2002 (Itanium)
>
> 5.02.3790 Windows Server 2003 or Windows XP x64 Edition (AMD64/EM64T)
>
> or Windows XP 64-Bit Edition Version
>   2003 (Itanium)
>
> 6.0.6000 Windows Vista
>
> 6.0.6001 Windows Vista with Service Pack 1 or Windows Server 2008
>
> 6.01.7600 Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2

>

And:

> OnlyBelowVersion Basically the
>   opposite of MinVersion. Specifies the
>   minimum Windows and Windows NT version
>   for the entry not to be processed. For
>   example, if you put 4.1,5.0 and the
>   user is running Windows 95 or NT 4.0
>   the entry will be processed, but if
>   the user is running Windows 98 (which
>   reports its version as 4.1) or Windows
>   2000 (which reports its version as NT
>   5.0), it will not be processed. Putting "0" for one of the versions
>   means there is no upper version limit.
>   Build numbers and/or service pack
>   levels may be included in the version
>   numbers. This overrides any
>   OnlyBelowVersion directive in the
>   script's [Setup] section.
>
> An entry without an OnlyBelowVersion
>   parameter is always processed, unless
>   other parameters say it shouldn't be.
>
> Example: OnlyBelowVersion: 4.1,5.0

Comment: "Inno Setup no longer supports Windows 95/98/Me"